# TableView to PDF add Padding to Page

Tags: ios, uitableview, pdf, swift

I create a PDF File from my UITableView using this Code:

```
var priorBounds:CGRect = self.tableView.bounds;

var fittedSize:CGSize = self.tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(priorBounds.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height))
self.tableView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, fittedSize.width, fittedSize.height);

var pdfPageBounds:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 792, 612); // Change this as your need
var pdfData = NSMutableData()

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil)

for var pageOriginY:CGFloat = 0; pageOriginY < fittedSize.height; pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height {

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil);       
    CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());      
    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -pageOriginY)
    self.tableView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

self.tableView.bounds = priorBounds; // Reset the tableView

let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
var pdfFileName = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("testfilewnew.pdf")

pdfData.writeToFile(pdfFileName, atomically: true)
```

It works fine, but the PDF fills out the whole Page of my PDF. I would like to add a Padding, and for Example a Title (on the first Page) and a Footer to every Page.

I am quite new using this PDF Export, i am not able to find a way to solve that. Can anyone help me, or bring me into the right direction?

Any help would be greatly apprechiated.

Comment: were you able to get a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a table that fits within the page by creating the table with slightly less width and height than the table.
Try this:

```
let paperA4 = CGRect(x: -25, y: 25, width: 612, height: 892);
let pageWithMargin = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: paperA4.width-50, height: paperA4.height-50);

        var fittedSize:CGSize = self.tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(pageWithMargin.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height))
        self.tableView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, fittedSize.size.width, fittedSize.height);

        var pdfData = NSMutableData()


        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, paperA4, nil)

        for var pageOriginY:CGFloat = 0; pageOriginY < fittedSize.height; pageOriginY += paperA4.size.height {

            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(paperA4, nil);

            CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

            CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, -pageOriginY)

            self.tableView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        }

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

        self.tableView.bounds = pageWithMargin; // Reset the tableView


        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
        var pdfFileName = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("testfilewnew.pdf")

        pdfData.writeToFile(pdfFileName, atomically: true)
```